# Django rest framework изменить OPTIONS

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Ответ при запросе к API (метод OPTIONS):

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "name": "User",
    "description": "",
    "renders": [
        "application/json",
        "text/html"
    ],
    "parses": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ],
    "actions": {
        "POST": {
            "username": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": true,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "Имя пользователя",
                "help_text": "Обязательное поле. Не более 150 символов. Только буквы, цифры и символы @/./+/-/_.",
                "max_length": 150
            },
            "password": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": true,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "Пароль",
                "max_length": 128
            },
            "is_not_password": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": true,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "Is not password"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И хочу что-бы явно отдавал что `is_not_password` это пароль, что-бы было описания типа, и хоть задан `input_type` он скрывается но в Web (в отладке api в django rest framework)

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_not_password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'is_not_password')
```

Вопрос в том, как задать доп. параметр или изменить тип на пароля что-бы клиент при запросе `OPTIONS` понимал что это пароль и скрывал его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там в целом по методу OPTIONS нет никаких конвенций по полю password, но если ты что-то хочешь добавить от себя, то можно переопределить у вьюхи `metadata_class` и выводить любую структуру.

Подробнее в официальной доке: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/

Comment: спасибо, но воспользовался вариантом c `DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS`

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ [@kidig](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188365/kidig),

Задал в `DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS` свой `class`:

```
#  settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'app.core.MinimalMetadata',
}
```

Сам `class`, и функция `get_field_info` осталась почти неизменной, но был добавлено новое поле в `attrs`:

```
# MinimalMetadata.py
from collections import OrderedDict

from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.metadata import SimpleMetadata


class MinimalMetadata(SimpleMetadata):
    """
    Don't include field and other information for `OPTIONS` requests.
    Just return the name and description.
    """

    def get_field_info(self, field):
        """
        Given an instance of a serializer field, return a dictionary
        of metadata about it.
        """
        field_info = OrderedDict()
        field_info['type'] = self.label_lookup[field]
        field_info['required'] = getattr(field, 'required', False)

        #  Было добавлено поле `write_only`
        attrs = [
            'read_only', 'label', 'help_text',
            'min_length', 'max_length',
            'min_value', 'max_value',
            'write_only'
        ]

        for attr in attrs:
            value = getattr(field, attr, None)
            if value is not None and value != '':
                field_info[attr] = force_text(value, strings_only=True)

        if getattr(field, 'child', None):
            field_info['child'] = self.get_field_info(field.child)
        elif getattr(field, 'fields', None):
            field_info['children'] = self.get_serializer_info(field)

        if (not field_info.get('read_only') and
                not isinstance(field, (serializers.RelatedField, serializers.ManyRelatedField)) and
                hasattr(field, 'choices')):
            field_info['choices'] = [
                {
                    'value': choice_value,
                    'display_name': force_text(choice_name, strings_only=True)
                }
                for choice_value, choice_name in field.choices.items()
            ]

        return field_info
```

И задал в `serializers.py` для `password` параметр `write_only` (и мне кажется логично что поля со значением `write_only = True` будет недоступно для просмотра):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

Answer (score 0):

Для себя решил вот таким нехитрым способом. [использовал этот ответ](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2675)

```
class MinimalMetadata(SimpleMetadata):
...
def get_field_info(self, field, field_name=None):
    """
    Given an instance of a serializer field, return a dictionary
    of metadata about it.
    """
    field_info = OrderedDict()

    # сдесь я переипользую совет от разработчиков:
    style = getattr(field, 'style', False)
    input_type = style.get('input_type') if style else False
    field_info['type'] = input_type or self.label_lookup[field]

    field_info['required'] = False if self.is_get_request else getattr(field, 'required', False)
    field_info['read_only'] = self.is_get_request or getattr(field, 'read_only', None)

    attrs = [
        'label', 'help_text',
        'min_length', 'max_length',
        'min_value', 'max_value',
    ]

    for attr in attrs:
        value = getattr(field, attr, None)
        if value is not None and value != '':
            field_info[attr] = force_text(value, strings_only=True)
   ...
```